# Merging(Joining) 2 huge flat files in Solaris, using an index column(first field)

Tags: unix, solaris

I have 2 huge flat files in Unix(Solaris), each say about 500-600 GB. And i need join and merge the 2 files into a single flat file using the first column which would be a key index column. How could i do it in an optimized way?

Basically it should be an inner join between the 2 flat files. Reason try to use flat files is, we have a 2 huge table that have been split into 2 separate tables, and that is extracted into 2 flat files, and i am trying to join it at Unix level instead of at database level.

I did use the below commands :

```
sort -n file1 > file_temp1;
sort -n file2 > file_temp2;
join -j 1 -t';' file_temp1 file_temp2 > Final
```

It works fine with sort as the 1st field is the index column. However when the join happens, i get hardly 2% of the data in the Final file. So just was trying to understand what mistake i am doing in the join command? Both the files contain about .2 million records and all of the records are matching between the 2 files. I want to have a performance check if the join made at unix would be better than that performed at the database level. Sorry for incomplete question! The first field is a numeric index field. do we have something like a"-n" switch to indicate the join that the first field is a numeric index?

Comment: An optimized way?  Don't use flat files for a terabyte of data. Given that much data, it'd be much faster to load the data into a database to merge the data into a single sorted output.  Databases are *designed* to handle that much data.  Command-line tools such as `awk` or `sort` really aren't.

Comment: OP only states the the first column is an index, so `cat file1 file2 > newfile` is a way to merge them. For other requirements he should edit his question.

Comment: Sorry yes the question was incomplete have added more information. any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of join? (LEFT/RIGHT/FULL ...) Are all keys present in both tables? Are all keys unique in both tables ?

Comment: Its just a simple inner join, yes all the keys are present in both files, all keys are unique. Both files have about .2 million records, exact same count of records, and all the keys sorted.

Comment: `Both the files contain about .2 million records` Which implies that: 1) you have very long records 2) an index for both files could be kept in memory.

Comment: Yes sure, Would you be able to assist me with some command for it? I am not that great in unix, But want to have this done in Unix not at the database level.

Comment: I am actually at the final step of a very good solution, And this join is just stopping me from it :(

Comment: Your `sort;sort; join` should work fine enough. BTW: For testing/building you could use a small subset of the two files, for example: records that start with `10` ...

Comment: Yes, exactly i did that. Basically i have 2 big tables in a database, and i have extracted the data into 2 flat files, and need to join it at unix level and load it back into a single table. I did try joining it with few records, and the solution does work. When i did join the 2 tables at database i have 100 percent matching records, So at the unix level as well it should match 100% and that is where i am stuck.

Comment: There  is a strange pattern of records being filtered after the join, say 999, 9990, 9991-9999, 99990, 99991-99999 are the keys that are in the final file after join. when i have keys from 747 till 225102

Comment: Could be leading (or trailing) whitespace in the keys of one of the files. (assuming ASCII files) BTW: You should **not** `sort -n`, since join has no corresponding `-n` flag ...

Comment: Ah, Yes there was one more thing, the reason why i added -n was if i simply use sort, then i again have a similar issue where the sort order is from smaller number to bigger number however with exceptions like order of keys being 700-998, 999, 9990, 99999. So really stuck up, Yes both the files are ASCII files. let me try removing the -n option.

Comment: Yes, after removing the -n on sort, i am able to match and join almost 90% of the data but not 100%, which is still an issue. The index field is a big int field, so there is no character at the beginning or at the end of the column when extracting it from the database, so still wondering! Sorry bothering you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **not** `sort -n`, since join has no corresponding `-n` flag. Just keep all the leading/trailing whitespace as it is:

```
#!/bin/sh

sort -t';' -k 1 file1 > file1.srt
sort -t';' -k 1 file2 > file2.srt

join -t';' -1 1 -2 1 file1.srt file2.srt > both

#cat both
```

Comment: I just tried it. Thanks, Yes one mistake is since join does'nt have -n should not use -n on sort. I did try this morning. But actually still not getting 100% of the data. For sure i have all the keys in here, because the same 2 tables i have been joining from a couple of day with 100% match. So not able to understand where exactly i am missing.

Comment: Most probably differences in whitespace between the two files. Or even leading zeros in the keys.

Comment: Yes i have been parsing the filest, there are no leading zeros or blanks. But since i feel there is some issue from my end for sure in this case. I accept your answer. Thanks for your time!!!